# Create Database from docker-compose.yml

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, bitnami

I'm trying create a new database called "slack-ruby-bot-server-events_sample_development" from my docker-compose.yml, but when I enter into the container for check the databases, sadly does not exist.

Here my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

services:
      hermes:
              depends_on:
                      - mongodb
              build:
                      context: ./hermes-app/
              container_name: hermes
              tty: true
              ports:
                      - "5000:5000"
              networks:
                      - netrmes
      mongodb:
              image: 'bitnami/mongodb:5.0.8'
              container_name: mongodb
              restart: on-failure
              environment:
                          - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=${MONGODB_DATABASE}
                          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGODB_ROOT_USER}
                          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
              ports:
                    - "27017:27017"
              volumes:
                      - 'mongodb_data:/bitnami/mongodb'
              networks:
                    - netrmes

networks:
          netrmes:
                  driver: bridge

volumes:
  mongodb_data:
    driver: local
```

The root_user and root_password is created successfully, but when i run the command "mongosh" into the container, the database in use is "test".

Anyone knows the way to set up that?, thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I think this variable "MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE" is just used to defined the default DB that the
> JS scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js default to if you
> insert some data or init something (indexes, create timeseries
> collections, …). It’s like the default use myDB that you can use.
>
> If you don’t create anything in that DB (I don’t see any script in
> here) then nothing happens and the DB isn’t created. MongoDB will
> create it if you actually store something in there. Else there is no
> reason to create an empty vessel.

Post: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/is-database-not-initialized-when-spinning-up-a-mongodb-docker-container/148786